# Перевод исходного кода python в бинарный

Tags: python, hex, binary

Пытаюсь перевести код в бинарные данные, потом выполнить его.

Исходный код:

```
exec(print(123))
```

Переведенный код:

```
\x65\x78\x65\x63\x28\x22\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x31\x32\x33\x29\x22\x29
```

При записи этой строки в переменную, выполнение кода не происходит.

Переводил так:

```
a = 'exec("print(123)")'
print('\\x'.join([codecs.encode(bytes(x, 'utf8'), 'hex').decode('utf8') for x in a]))
```

Что не так? Правильно ли я перевожу?

*Python  3*

Comment: Всё не так. Исходный код неправильный. Он равнозначен: `exec(None)` что ведёт к TypeError. Что такое "бинарные данные" в контексте вопроса не ясно. Уже одно наличие "\\x" говорит, что код сломанный. Как вы собираетесь их исполнять? Вы пытаетесь pyc файл создать? Или просто code объект? Что мешает исходный код напрямую передать?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что словосочетание "бинарный код" не всегда обозначает то, что можно выполнить как программу.

В данном случае "бинарная строка" - это просто указание на то, что с данными нужно работать просто как с последовательностью  байтов.

То есть, это просто такая специфическая разновидность строки. Никакого отношения к бинарному программному коду оно не имеет, и выполнить это нельзя.

Comment: И даже это неверно. Результат, выводимый print() в последнем примере  у автора Юникодная строка, а не bytes.

Comment: @jfs, про итоговый результат я и не писал. Там вообще не понятно, что он надеялся получить в качестве итогового результата. Просто я увидел, что у него там используется bytes, и предположил, что он просто не понимает разницы между "бинарными данными" и "бинарным исполняемым кодом". На этом непонимании, насколько я понял, у него вся путаница и происходит.